# formatting empty fields pandas dataframe to text file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this df

```
ID Field1  Field2  Field3
1    1        1       1
2    2        3       1
3    4        5       8
```

I want to export this to a formatted text file (which I know how to do). 
My issue is the formatted text file has 10 formats (i.e. 10 fields) and so 7 do not exist in my df. For columns/formats that do not exist, I want the text file to just leave those columns as blank (formatted correctly).

For example

```
fmt='%2s%10s%3s%1.0f%4s%1s%4.0f%02.0f%02.0f%4.0f' 
np.savetxt('df.txt',df.values,fmt=fmt)
```

In the above example the first 3 formats are for my df columns and the next 7 should be blank/spaces but of the correct format (i.e. %4s would be 4 spaces).

If I have the 10 field names in a list can I somehow make this happen such that if the field name is in the list and in my df that it gets populated and if not then the field will be formatted correctly blank?

Comment: Could you include an example of what you would like the final output to look like.

Comment: you probably want `df.reindex([Field1, Field2, ...], axis=1, fill_value='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I will need a bit more info on how you are collecting this data to be more specific. However, this is what I would do. Create an empty column in the data frame and format that empty space to whatever space a normal data point would take.

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 'N/A'],
              [2, 3, 1, 'N/A'],
              [4, 5, 8, 'N/A']])

b = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4'])
b=b.replace('N/A', '')
np.savetxt(r'df.txt', b.values, fmt='%4s')
```